# Replace "toggle" with "animate"

Tags: jquery, navigation, toggle

This jQuery snippet shows or hides submenu item when a menu link is clicked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.main-navigation ul li a').click(function() {
   var li = $(this).closest('li');
   if(li.has('ul'))
        li.find('ul').toggle(100);
});

});
```

How can similar effect be achieved with "animate" rather than "toggle"?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: what kind of animation do you want? you have several ones `.slideToggle()` and `.fadeToggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several predefined toggles like

`.slideToggle()` and `.fadeToggle()`

Or you can use this way to toggle animations

```
$('.main-navigation ul li a').toggle(
function()
{
  $('#something').animate({
    height: "100"
  }, 500);
},
function()
{
  $('#something').animate({
    height: "200"
  }, 500);
});
```

---

Since `.toggle()` with 2 handlers is deprecated

here is the way you should do it

```
var toggle = false;

$('#foo').click(function() {
  if (toggle) {
    $("#bar").hide();
  } else {
    $("#bar").show();
  }
  toggle = !toggle;
});
```

here you have a working example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BwKc9/1/

Comment: That overload of `.toggle()` is deprecated; you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Ian thanks, i'll update my answer shortly with a different way

Comment: So, something like this? $('.main-navigation ul li a').click(function() {
   var li = $(this).closest('li');
   if(li.has('ul'))
        li.find('ul').slideToggle(150);
});

Comment: @Figaro yes, that would work but please see my updated answer for correct solution.

Comment: @Pedro, coud you please adapt your "foo" and "bar" example to my specific situation? I tried, but something isn't working right. Here's what I did: var toggle = false;

 $('ul li a').click(function () {
    var li = $(this).closest('li'); 
    if(li.has('ul')) {
   if (toggle) {
  li.find('ul').hide();
    } else {
      li.find('ul').show();
    }
 }
});

Comment: @Figaro you're missing the `toggle = !toggle;` at the end of the click function. this switches the variable toggle from false to true and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Probably somthing using slide*() transitions?

```
   $('ul li a').click(function () {
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    var ul;
    if (li.has('ul')) {
       ul = li.find('ul').slideToggle('slow');  // SlideToggle this to slideUp/down based on current state.
     }
        $('ul.subMenu:visible').not(ul).slideUp('slow');//slideUp all other menus

    });
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fH4Ay/)

Comment: is it possible that you can put the menu piece and css, js you are using in a fiddle wher eyou can replicate the problems...?

Comment: Fiddle is blocked by my network's IT people, unfortunately, @PSL.

Answer (score 1):

If your browser supports CSS3, why not let CSS do the animation by toggling a specific class?

It's really easy, and [a better choice](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/).

Check out this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/E9JyN/1/).

All I changed in your code was this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($
    $('ul li').click(function() {
       var li = $(this).closest('li');
       if(li.has('ul'))
           li.find('ul').toggleClass('open'); // <- this line!
    });
});
```

Now, you probably guessed that the `open` class opens the sub menu. It's sliding down because of this short css snippet:

```
ul li > ul {
    max-height: 0;  
    transition: all 1s;
}

ul li > ul.open {
    max-height: 140px;
}
```

And its really easy to modify as well! For fun, let's say you want to scale-fade-slide in the sub menu? That's so easy, even my grandmother could do it (with a little stackoverflow searching)!

Check it out the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/E9JyN/2/).

*Now if you want to use it, you may want to include all the necessary `-ms-`, `-o-`, `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes to your CSS3 properties.*